# How to add AggregateRating in GTM using DOM element Variables?

Tags: schema.org, google-tag-manager, json-ld

Here is the JSON-LD script that i use for implementing product schema in GTM using DOM variables.

```
<script>
var jsonData = {
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": {{productName}},
  "image": {{productImg}},
  "url": {{Page URL}},
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
"ratingValue": {{avgRating}},
    "reviewCount": {{ratingsCount}},
  }
  }

  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'application/ld+json';
  script.text = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
  $("head").append(script);
</script>
```

DOM Variable Configuration:

[image]

[image]

But while debugging the page, the avgRating and ratingsCount value showing 'null'.[image]

[image]

I am unable to find out where is the main error that the value not being extract from the page. How can i solve the problem..Please mention if there is any error in the schema code and the DOM variable configuration. Thanks in Advance..